# how to create a sharepoint list item when a work item change to completed in Devops?

Tags: devops, power-automate

When a task is done in Devops I want move it to SharePoint list, I heard I can use Power autmate but I don,t know how it will works? Or I go Another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible!
There are many Power Automate Templates to use DevOps. I Found one that can solve your problem.
The template name is: "Create a SharePoint list item When an azure DevOps work is created".

Link to a template:
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/fb02323890b140b697cb1249be2e0e0d/track-completed-tasks-for-data-visualization/

[Azure DevOps Templates on Power Automate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTldz.png)

Comment: Thank you so much, aanother question when it comes to NOW field , what should the input be?